# OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument ( Fails randomly while processing a file)

Tags: python, json, scripting

I run this python code which reads a file and uploads data to the engine.
It runs fine, however out of a sudden it fails and throws the error in the middle.
I did some research but wasn't able to find a solution that works.
below is the error

```
--- Logging error --- Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "C:\Python36\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 998, in emit     self.flush()   
File "C:\Python36\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 978, in flush     self.stream.flush() 
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

below is the code:

```
import argparse
import httplib2
import numpy as np
import pprint
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from oauth2client import GOOGLE_TOKEN_URI
from oauth2client.client import OAuth2Credentials, 
HttpAccessTokenRefreshError
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date, timedelta
from dateutil.parser import parse
import time
import os
import json
import datetime
import logging
from datetime import datetime
import pysftp
import warnings
 header = []
 final_report = ""

logging.basicConfig(filename='Logs/DialogTech_To_DS3' + date.today().strftime("%Y.%m.%d"), level=logging.INFO)
def create_credentials(client_id, client_secret, refresh_token):
"""Create Google OAuth2 credentials.

Returns:
    OAuth2Credentials
"""
return OAuth2Credentials(access_token=None,
                         client_id=client_id,
                         client_secret=client_secret,
                         refresh_token=refresh_token,
                         token_expiry=None,
                         token_uri=GOOGLE_TOKEN_URI,
                         user_agent=None)

service = build('doubleclicksearch', 'v2', http=http)
return service

for filename in os.listdir('J:/SharedFolder/Feeds/Data/'):
    file = 'J:/SharedFolder/Feeds/Data/' + filename
    if filename.startswith('Daily_'):
        print(filename)
        file_name = filename
        logging.info("Uploading Conversions from " + filename)
        columns = ['Timestamp', 'GCLID', 'camp', 'OrderID', 'Orders', 'Revenue',
                   'OrderLevelDiscount', 'Units', 'OutOfStockViews', 'ScorecardApplied', 'StoreLocator']

        data = pd.read_csv(file, delimiter='\t')
        data['Revenue'] = data['Revenue'].map(lambda x: '{:.2f}'.format(x))
        data['OrderID'] = data['OrderID'].map(lambda x: '{:.0f}'.format(x))
        #data['OrderID'] = data['OrderID'].apply(lambda x: int(x) if "." in str(x) else x)

        pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
        pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)

        dir = 'J:/SharedFolder/Feeds/Data/'
        # data.to_csv(dir + 'FNS_' + filename.replace('Daily_', '').replace('.txt', '') + '.csv')

        print(data.head(data['Timestamp'].count()))
        print(data['Timestamp'].count())

        for index, row in data.iterrows():
            dt = parse(row['Timestamp'])
            millisecond = int(round(dt.timestamp() * 1000))
            #print(row)

            if row['Orders'] > 0:
                order_revenue_upload(service, row['GCLID'], str(row['OrderID']) + str(index), millisecond, row['Revenue'], row['Orders'])
            if row['OrderLevelDiscount'] > 0:
                order_level_discount_upload(service, row['GCLID'], str(row['OrderID']) + "_OLD_" + str(index), millisecond, row['OrderLevelDiscount'])
            if row['Units'] > 0:
                units_upload(service, row['GCLID'], str(row['OrderID']) + "_U_" + str(index), millisecond, row['Units'])
            if row['OutOfStockViews'] > 0:
                out_of_stock_views_upload(service, row['GCLID'], str(row['OrderID']) + "_OOSV_" + str(index), millisecond, row['OutOfStockViews'])
            if row['ScorecardApplied'] > 0:
                score_card_applied_upload(service, row['GCLID'], str(row['OrderID']) + "_SCA_" + str(index), millisecond, row['ScorecardApplied'])
            if row['StoreLocator'] > 0:
                store_locator_upload(service, row['GCLID'], str(row['OrderID']) + "_SL_" + str(index), millisecond, row['StoreLocator'])

  os.rename(file, 'J:/SharedFolder/Feeds/Data/' + file_name)
```

Comment: Is it possible that any filenames that you are logging are not encodable using your filesystem's default encoding (as defined [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdout)?)

Comment: I dont think so. The file can be accessed.

Answer (score 4):

You are on windows that uses backslash as path separator `\`. However for python this is escape char, so you need to use forward slash or raw string or escape the backslash. change these types of addresses:

```
'J:/SharedFolder/Feeds/Data/'
```

to this one:

```
r'J:\SharedFolder\Feeds\Data\'
```

or

```
'J:\\SharedFolder\\Feeds\\Data\\'
```

Comment: But, if it's the case. It should fail at the beginning right?. but this fails in the randomly while processing few rows.

Comment: @Moh'dAnsar Do what I say and test it. is it still throw same error?

Comment: i did the changes and did a test run. It's running right now, will update if it errors out.

Comment: @Moh'dAnsar Can you share with us full stack trace of what python shows you as a error ? I think the error you show in the question is something incomplete...

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it solve my problem.

Comment: but how to do this change? if there are several variables concat with the '/', there is no raw string.

Answer (score 0):

After doing much research, I found a resolution that worked out for me,
instead of using

```
  logging.basicConfig(filename='Logs/DialogTech_To_DS3' + date.today().strftime("%Y.%m.%d"), level=logging.INFO)
```

i used

```
  folder = '//MappedDrive/Share/Logs\\DialogTechToDS3 test '

  logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, filename=folder + date.today().strftime("%m.%d.%Y")+'.log', filemode='w')
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this same error and after a long search I just realised it was due to the fact that the log file produced was corrupted.

Deleting the log file solved the issue !!!

Just delete the file which is in the path: pathLog

```
# At the beginning of the app, I launch a function that defined the logger handler
# Path to the log file
pathLog =  os.path.join( folder, r'log\laurent.log' )
file_handler =  logging.FileHandler(pathLog )

# OTHER things I defined (which are not relevant for the question
file_handler.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
file_handler_format = '%(asctime)s | %(levelname)s | %(filename)s | %(lineno)d: %(message)s' 
file_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(file_handler_format))
# ADD the Handler
logger.addHandler(file_handler)
```