# OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument during logging

Tags: python, exception, logging

During capturing an exception, I attempt to log the traceback using the logging module.  The logging module is logging to disk.  During the logging, I get another exception with the logging.  I have no idea what in the traceback is causing the logging to fail.

logging snippet

```
            self.logger.debug(
                traceback.format_exc(),
                job_name=self.job_name,
                address=self.short_wallet_address
            )
```

Crash stack

```
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxx\OneDrive\Desktop\crypto\SwapShop\SwapShop\modules\NonceManager.py", line 94, in run
    self.sc.w3.eth.getTransactionCount(
  File "C:\Users\xxx\OneDrive\Desktop\crypto\SwapShop\lib\site-packages\web3\module.py", line 57, in caller
    result = w3.manager.request_blocking(method_str,
  File "C:\Users\xxx\OneDrive\Desktop\crypto\SwapShop\lib\site-packages\web3\manager.py", line 187, in request_blocking
    return self.formatted_response(response,
  File "C:\Users\xxx\OneDrive\Desktop\crypto\SwapShop\lib\site-packages\web3\manager.py", line 168, in formatted_response
    raise ValueError(response["error"])
ValueError: {'code': -32603, 'message': 'RPCError'}

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1087, in emit
    self.flush()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1067, in flush
    self.stream.flush()
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
Call stack:
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 129, in _main
    return self._bootstrap(parent_sentinel)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\xxx\OneDrive\Desktop\crypto\SwapShop\SwapShop\modules\NonceManager.py", line 106, in run
    self.logger.debug(
Message: '[\x1b[37m\x1b[1mNonceManager_poly - 0xF21...EEF1\x1b[0m]: Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "C:\\Users\\xxx\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\crypto\\SwapShop\\SwapShop\\modules\\NonceManager.py", line 94, in run\n    self.sc.w3.eth.getTransactionCount(\n  File "C:\\Users\\xxx\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\crypto\\SwapShop\\lib\\site-packages\\web3\\module.py", line 57, in caller\n    result = w3.manager.request_blocking(method_str,\n  File "C:\\Users\\xxx\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\crypto\\SwapShop\\lib\\site-packages\\web3\\manager.py", line 187, in request_blocking\n    return self.formatted_response(response,\n  File "C:\\Users\\xxx\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\crypto\\SwapShop\\lib\\site-packages\\web3\\manager.py", line 168, in formatted_response\n    raise ValueError(response["error"])\nValueError: {\'code\': -32603, \'message\': \'RPCError\'}\n'
Arguments: ()
2021-09-02 12:57:17 [NonceManager_poly - 0xF21...EEF1]: A non-recoverable error occurred.  Check logs for details.
Process p4_poly_mainnet_waultswap_WMATIC-WEXPOLY_0xF21...EEF1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxx\OneDrive\Desktop\crypto\SwapShop\SwapShop\modules\StakingProcess.py", line 435, in claim_by_amount
    self.pending_reward = self.sc.get_pending_reward_amount(
  File "C:\Users\xxx\OneDrive\Desktop\crypto\SwapShop\SwapShop\modules\SwapClient.py", line 1341, in get_pending_reward_amount
    pending_reward = self.master_contract.functions.pendingWex(
  File "C:\Users\xxx\OneDrive\Desktop\crypto\SwapShop\lib\site-packages\web3\contract.py", line 957, in call
    return call_contract_function(
  File "C:\Users\xxx\OneDrive\Desktop\crypto\SwapShop\lib\site-packages\web3\contract.py", line 1501, in call_contract_function
    return_data = web3.eth.call(
  File "C:\Users\xxx\OneDrive\Desktop\crypto\SwapShop\lib\site-packages\web3\module.py", line 57, in caller
    result = w3.manager.request_blocking(method_str,
  File "C:\Users\xxx\OneDrive\Desktop\crypto\SwapShop\lib\site-packages\web3\manager.py", line 187, in request_blocking
    return self.formatted_response(response,
  File "C:\Users\xxx\OneDrive\Desktop\crypto\SwapShop\lib\site-packages\web3\manager.py", line 168, in formatted_response
    raise ValueError(response["error"])
ValueError: {'code': -32603, 'message': 'RPCError'}
```

Comment: Hi @NetMan, sorry to revive this a looong time after you asked. I'm encountering the same problem.

My log file resides on a network share. Logging works fine for a long time (1-2 days? haven't timed it) and then I start getting OSError 22 on every logging entry. I'm thinking maybe the network resource disconnects the file after it's open too long?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your logfile path is correct ? Searching for "file flush errno 22" leads to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55200692/11384184) which seems to indicate that an incorrect path would cause this issue, and you specifically mentionned you were writing the logs to a file.

Comment: I don't believe the path is the problem.  I have plenty of other logging entries in the logfile using the same logger object.